# Proof that Connected Sets that Intersect a Common Set Form a Connected Union?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I'm working through a real analysis textbook and ran into the following problem which has stumped me.

> Suppose that $X$ is the union of $T$ and sets $S_n$.  Suppose that $T$ is connected, and that each set $S_n$ is connected. Suppose that for every index $n$, $T\cap S_n\ne\emptyset$. Prove that $X$ is connected.

I understand the use of this problem since I ran into it earlier trying to prove that the Cartesian product of connected sets is connected. I couldn't figure anything out then either, so I opted for a different strategy where I took a union of a particular horizontal and vertical slice and then extended. While such a strategy may work here, I am particularly wary of the case where $S_n$ may be an infinite set which would cause problems in extending this (since it may not always work then).

Hints rather than a more full solution would be appreciated, though if I fail horribly to understand a hint I may be tempted to request further help in comments.

Comment: Hint: Suppose that $X$ is not connected and fix disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $U\cap X\neq\emptyset$ and $V\cap X\neq\emptyset$. What happens with each $S_n$? Could it intersect both $U$ and $V$? And what happens with $T$?

Comment: @AndréPorto I'm seeing similarities in this hint to what I ultimately used for the cartesian product problem which in hindsight makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $C$ be a connected component of $X$. Show that if $C\cap T\ne\varnothing$, then $T\subseteq C$, and that if $T\cap S_n\ne\varnothing$ for some $n$, then $S_n\subseteq C$.